# How does this work?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, vector

In applications like Adobe Illustrator, they have a way to simplify a path. I'm not sure how this works exactly. Given a path with points which have 2 bezier handles each (for cubic bezier), how could I go about simplifying the path?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Douglas–Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) it is an algorithm for reducing the number of points in a curve that is approximated by a series of points. It is frequently used in GIS solutions.

Comment: I wrote an answer with a little animation of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm if you are interested... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937976/2836621